# Semantic syntax highlighter (without inline CSS)

Tags: linux, open-source, html, css

I’m looking for a tool that takes code as input and outputs this code as syntax highlighted HTML+CSS.

It can either be a local tool (running natively on GNU/Linux) or a self-hosted web app (Linux server). In either case, it must be FLOSS.

#### Input

I only need support for "Web languages" (i.e., XML, HTML, CSS and JavaScript). But support for more languages is welcome, of course.

The tool doesn’t have to guess the language; I’m fine with selecting it.

#### Output

It should **escape** characters that might conflict with (X)HTML, e.g. `<` as `&lt;`.

It should use only **`div` and `span` elements** to markup the code.

It should not use the `style` attribute! Either use the `style` element (so I can copy the CSS and paste it into my stylesheet) or offer a **separate CSS** file.

For that, it should use **`class` attributes** (`data-*` is okay, too). At best it uses semantic class values, and some kind of prefix to avoid name conflicts.

Just to give a poor example, here is an HTML input followed by an acceptable output:

```
<p>Lheben teil brann i annon ar <b id="foo">neledh</b> neledhi gar godrebh.</p>
```

```
<span class="sh-html-tag">&lt;p&gt;</span>Lheben teil brann i annon ar <span class="sh-html-tag">&lt;b <span class="sh-html-attribute">id="foo"</span>&gt;</span>neledh<span class="sh-html-tag">&lt;/b&gt;</span> neledhi gar godrebh.<span class="sh-html-tag">&lt;/p&gt;</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

I once wrote that for **[iFAQMaker](http://projects.izzysoft.de/trac/ifaqmaker/)**, which is no longer maintained. An example of code output you can find in the [Demo page](http://projects.izzysoft.de/trac/ifaqmaker/wiki/Demo):

[image: iFAQMaker Demo]

Input are basically text files with macros supported. This example uses the `sqlfile` macro, resulting in the text syntax highlighted as SQL, plus a link to download the original file. There are `*file` macros available for SQL, PHP, and Shell, and you can extend the API with additional ones if needed.

How does it fit your requirements:

- **self-hosted web app (Linux server):** *iFAQMaker* is a PHP application/script.
- **FLOSS:** Yes (GPLv2)
- **XML, HTML, CSS and JavaScript:** As it ships, only SQL, PHP, and Shell. Given a keyword list, you can easily add all languages you want.
- **escape characters:** Yes, it does.
- **should use only div and span elements to markup the code:** Yupp.
- **not use the style attribute:** Nope. Uses CSS classes with a specific (external) stylesheet

Not a perfect match (as you'd have to create the keyword lists for your major languages first), but I hope it's useful nevertheless. I'm using it a lot on my websites for exactly this: displaying scripts inline syntax-highlighted, while at the same time offering them for download.